# How to show the background grid on area chart?

Tags: amcharts

I need to show the grid lines on area chart within the background. I am working on amcharts area chart. I need the chart like attachment image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For v4, please check out our guide on [Axis Ranges for Series](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/axis-ranges/#Using_with_series).

Our [Chart With Gaps In Data demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/chart-with-gaps-in-data/) does exactly what's shown in your screenshot:

[image: screenshot of our demo with areas colored by their value along the y axis]

The parts that allow the grid lines to come through is that the `fill`s are transparent via `fillOpacity`:

```js
// There's no series.fill because it has its own color already
series.fillOpacity = 0.2;

// [...]
range.contents.stroke = chart.colors.getIndex(2);
range.contents.fill = range.contents.stroke;
range.contents.fillOpacity = 0.2;
```

Let us know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `gridAboveGraphs` and set it to true in your chart config.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivcontainer", {
  "gridAboveGraphs": true
});
```

Comment: fwiw this is a amCharts v3 answer. OP didn't specify his version.